# What's wrong with my calculation?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

I want to find the area of a triangle with vertices $\left(0,0\right)$, $\left(2,1\right)$, and $\left(2,0\right)$ with $\iint _A\left(2x-3y\right)dx \ dy$, i think the limits of the integral are $0\le x\le 2$ and $0\le y\le 1$. So to find the area of this triangle,

> $\int _{x=0}^2dx\int _{y=0}^1\left(2x-3y\right)dy=\int _0^2\left(2x-\frac{3}{2}\right)dx=1$

but my answer is incorrect because according to my book the correct answer is $\frac{5}{3}$. What's wrong with my calculation? Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: You are integrating over a rectangle, not a triangle. (And the integral is not an area, by the way.)

Comment: The area of the triangle is indeed $1$. The fact that the correct answer is $\frac53$ is a big clue that you are not trying to find the area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The limit in $y$ is the line $y=x/2$, so the integral is actually

$$\int_0^2 dx \, \int_0^{x/2} dy \, (2 x-3 y)$$

The answer is indeed $5/3$.

Comment: is $\frac{x}{2}$ the slope of this triangle of the vertices $\left(0,0\right)$ and $\left(2,1\right)$?

Comment: The slope of the hypotenuse of the triangle is $1/2$.  The equation of the hypotenuse is $y=x/2$.

Comment: alright now i get it! thank you so much, sir!